# Octave plot points as animation

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I have the following octave script,

```
TOTAL_POINTS = 100;
figure(1)

for i=1:TOTAL_POINTS
   randX = rand(1); 
   randY = rand(1);

   scatter(randX, randY);
   hold on; 
endfor
```

When I run this by `octave script.m`, I get nothing. When I add the line `pause` to the end of this script, it works but I only see the plot after all the `100` points are plotted.

I want to see the plot point by point. Not after I plotted every single point.

PS: I have `Ubuntu`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) at the end of the iteration. At least that works in Matlab. It forces the interpreter to empty the graphic event queue.

If you include `pause` at the end of the iteration, `drawnow` may not be needed (`pause` already empties the event queue).  But I usually add it just in case.

Other comments:

- You don't need `hold on` at every iteration. It sufficies to do it once, at the beginning.
- You may want to freeze the axis to prevent auto-scaling when a new point is added

With these modifications, your code would become:

```
TOTAL_POINTS = 100;
figure(1)
hold on; 
axis([0 1 0 1]) %// set axis
axis manual %// prevent axis from auto-scaling
for i=1:TOTAL_POINTS
   randX = rand(1); 
   randY = rand(1);
   scatter(randX, randY);
   pause(.1) %// pause 0.1 seconds to slow things down
   drawnow
endfor
```