# Matlab Animation

Tags: matlab, animation, frame-rate, ode

I'm currently trying to animate a particle in 2D obeying a system of ODEs. I currently have the code below, based on examples online, but I really don't know how to proceed.

If anyone could offer assistance, I'd be most appreciative.

```
function Animation()
% Solving the systemP1 using ode45
sol=ode45(@systemP1,[0,0.0001],[10e-7,-1,10e-7,-1]); 
t = linspace(0,0.0001)
p = deval(sol,t);
% Xposition
x = p(1,:)'; 
xdot = p(2,:)' ;
% Yposition
y = p(3,:)'; 
ydot = p(4,:)' ;
position = [x, y];
% Trajectory of the particle
path = plot(position(1,1), position(1,2),'k');



end
```

Comment: You almost have it.  Let me write an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it correct.  What you can do is put the `plot` in a `for` loop and plot each point individually.  That way, you can see how the point moves in a more "real-time" sense.  Make sure that at end of the `for` loop, add `drawnow` at the end of the iteration.  It forces MATLAB to empty the graphic event queue.  I also add `pause` at the end as well just in case the drawing goes too fast.

Make sure you have a `hold on` statement at the beginning before the `for` loop.  I would also recommend freezing the axis to prevent auto scaling the axis when a new point is being the added.  As such, your code would be modified to be:

```
function Animation()
% Solving the systemP1 using ode45
sol=ode45(@systemP1,[0,0.0001],[10e-7,-1,10e-7,-1]); 
t = linspace(0,0.0001)
p = deval(sol,t);
% Xposition
x = p(1,:)'; 
xdot = p(2,:)' ;
% Yposition
y = p(3,:)'; 
ydot = p(4,:)' ;
position = [x, y];

%// Modifications start here
figure(1);
hold on;

%// Find limits of x and y axes
minX = min(x);
maxX = max(x);
minY = min(y);
maxY = max(y);

%// Prevent axis from auto-scaling
axis([minX maxX minY maxY]);
axis manual;

%//Plot each position vector over time
for idx = 1 : size(position,1)
    %//Trajectory of the particle
    plot(position(idx,1), position(idx,2),'k.', 'MarkerSize', 18);
    pause(0.1); %// Pause 0.1 seconds to slow things down. Remove if necessary
    drawnow;
end
end
```

The `MarkerSize` parameter changes the size of each point.  I set it to 18 as it looks large enough on my machine.  Make this larger or smaller according to your preference.  I don't see why `xdot` and `ydot` are defined, so I left it out of the code.  However, if you want to use these, basically replicate the same code I have above but for `xdot` and `ydot`.  If you'd like me to do this for you, let me know in a comment and I'll modify my post.

## Note

This post was inspired by Luis Mendo's post on plotting objects as animation.  That post can be found here: [Octave plot points as animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207286/octave-plot-points-as-animation/24207572#24207572)

Comment: Thank you very much! I really am grateful!!

Comment: @user3532764 - You're very welcome!  Did this work as you expected?

Comment: Almost, there is a Y in max(y). Also, the dots plotted are a bit too small to see properly, any way to make them larger? Thanks again!

Comment: @user3532764 Oops!  That should be small case.  Yes, you can also change the size of the dot.  I have just changed the code.  Take a look.